# counting strings in list using dictionary in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

i have a list of list with only  strings and i have to create a dictionary with  strinds as keys and their count in list  of list as value.
should look like this:

```
[[‘dolphin’, ‘bomb’, ‘spider’], [‘eye’, ‘bomb’, ‘fire’],
[‘spider’, ‘fire’, ‘lock’], [‘bomb’, ‘lock’, ‘tree’]]
```

and the output should be with every key in different line :

```
dolphin 1
bomb 3
spider 2
eye 1
fire 2
lock 2
tree 1
```

this is my code:

```
dic_count={}
count=1
def print_symbols_counts(deck):
    for i in range(len(deck)-1):
        for j in deck[i]:
            if j in deck[i+1]:
                dic_count[j]=count+1
            else:
                dic_count[j]=count
    return dic_count
```

but sudly i cant get the correct  output (this is my output):

```
{'dolphin': 1, 'bomb': 1, 'spider': 1, 'eye': 1, 'fire': 1, 'lock': 2}
```

thank you:)

Comment: Where you write `dic_count[j]=count+1`, in plain English, what is the intent of the line? Now, where does the value of `count` on the right-hand side come from? Similarly for `dic_count[j]=count`. When that line executes, how many times has the word `j` been seen? Therefore, what value should be stored as `dic_count`?

Comment: With the condition `if j in deck[i+1]:`, what purpose is *that* for? It seems like you need to handle `dic_count[j]` differently depending on... what condition, in plain English? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
llist2 = [["bomb", "bomb", "spider"], ["eye", "bomb", "fire","spider"], ["bomb", "lock", "tree","fire"]]

dictionary = {}
for i in llist2:
    for k in i:
        if k not in dictionary:
            dictionary[k]=1
        else:
            dictionary[k]+=1
#output

{'bomb': 4, 'spider': 2, 'eye': 1, 'fire': 2, 'lock': 1, 'tree': 1}
```

This should do the job.

The code iterates over every list in `llist2` then for each list, it checks if its elements are already a `key` in the `dictionary`. If not, it creates the key and assigns to it 1. If already in, it increments the count.

Answer (score 1):

You could just flatten the list and then use `Collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
flat_list = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]
result = Counter(flat_list)
```

See [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) and [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item).

**EDIT:** Since OP is not allowed to use `Counter`:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]
result = dict((x, flat_list.count(x)) for x in set(flat_list))
```

Comment: the thing is that i am not allowed to use counter